# Blurry Image rendered from iPhone camera

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine, textures, screen-resolution

I'm developing a photo-based game for iPhone in Unity and I'm coming across a resolution issue when accessing the device camera. The live image, rendered to a Texture, is noticeably pixelated, and the photo, when taken and saved to the photo gallery is similarly pixelated. It seems like the the image that is getting rendered to the Texture is a lower resolution than the native resolution of camera/screen but I'm unsure as to why that is. How can I resolve this problem? Thank you!

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PhoneCamera : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool camAvailable;
    private Texture defaultBackground;

    public static WebCamTexture backCam { get; set; }

    public RawImage background;
    public AspectRatioFitter fit;

    private void Start ()
    {
        defaultBackground = background.texture;
        WebCamDevice [] devices = WebCamTexture.devices;

        if (devices.Length == 0) {
            Debug.Log ("No camera detected");
            camAvailable = false;
            return;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < devices.Length; i++) {
            if (!devices [i].isFrontFacing) {
                backCam = new WebCamTexture (devices [i].name, Screen.width, Screen.height);
            }
        }

        if (backCam == null) {
            Debug.Log ("Unable to find back camera");
            return;
        }

        backCam.Play ();
        background.texture = backCam;

        camAvailable = true;
    }

    private void Update ()
    {
        if (!camAvailable)
            return;

        float ratio = (float)backCam.width / (float)backCam.height;
        fit.aspectRatio = ratio;

        float scaleY = backCam.videoVerticallyMirrored ? -1f : 1f;
        background.rectTransform.localScale = new Vector3 (1f, scaleY, 1f);

        int orient = -backCam.videoRotationAngle;
        background.rectTransform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3 (0, 0, orient);
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the `Screen.width` and `Screen.height`? According to a Unity developer in [this](https://forum.unity.com/threads/ios-webcamtexture-displaying-wrong-resolution.186022/) forum post, Unity selects a capture resolution nearest to the resolution that you pass in.

Comment: Ah, I see, I was setting my texture resolution to the screen resolution, but I should have been setting it to the camera resolution. Texture is much crisper now.